# Spring Boot ContentDisposition not working correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, download, http-headers

i have the following code to download an Excel File from a Spring Boot 2.7.5 (Spring Web 5.3.23) `@GetMapping`.

```
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.attachment()
                                                              .filename("test-3.xlsx")
                                                              .build();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
    //headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + "test-7.xlsx");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                         .headers(headers)
                         .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
                         .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                         .body(resource);
```

I would like to use Springs [`ContentDisposition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.23/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ContentDisposition.html) object but it does not work. The File either get's not downloaded (Insomnia REST Client) or is displayed as binary data.

What works is the commented line:
`headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + "test-7.xlsx");`
and commenting the `headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition)` line.

Even the suggester somewhere on SO: `headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());` does not work.

Another problem is also that the generated filename looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas?